# Oracle query taking long time using Exist function

Tags: oracle

Folks, i have a code which run of two tables in oracle 10.2. These tables have huge chunk of data and while using the and exist function, it takes too long to give an answer. am i doing something wrong in below code.

```
SELECT  'Total' nationality,
        SUM(
          CASE
          WHEN new_store_code IN ('40022', '40041', '40021', '40023','40074')
          THEN amount
          END
        ) cy_all_sale
FROM    txn_2017_18 a
WHERE   (CONCEPT) = 'Home center'
AND     invoice_date <= (select To_DT from Data_Date)
And     Department_Code in ('306','307','308','309','310','311','312','313','314','315','318')
AND     EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM   txn_2016_17 b
          WHERE  a.member_card_number = b.member_card_number
          AND    (b.CONCEPT) = 'Home center'
          AND    invoice_date <= (select LY_To_DT from Data_Date)
          And    Department_Code in '306','307','308','309','310','311','312','313','314','315','318')
          AND     (a.CONCEPT) = (b.CONCEPT)
          and     A.New_Store_Code=B.New_Store_Code
        )
```

Comment: Ok, the issue i found out is, filtering the date from different table. (select LY_To_DT from Data_Date). if i hard code the dates then the query runs very fast. but why i am taking the dates from different table is becos i need to prepare this report every week for more than 100 locations. and to change the dates all the place is not feasible. any option??.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this approach, using 2 `sub select`, each from `txn_2017_18` & `txn_2016_17`, then `JOIN` them together as below. But first make sure your tables are properly index based on query condition.

```
SELECT
    'Total' nationality,
    SUM(amount) cy_all_sale
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM txn_2017_18
    WHERE
        new_store_code IN ('40022', '40041', '40021', '40023', '40074')
        AND CONCEPT = 'Home center'
        AND invoice_date <= (select To_DT from Data_Date)
        AND Department_Code in ('306','307','308','309','310','311','312','313','314','315','318')
) a
JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM txn_2016_17
    WHERE
        new_store_code IN ('40022', '40041', '40021', '40023', '40074')
        AND CONCEPT = 'Home center'
        AND invoice_date <= (select LY_To_DT from Data_Date)
        And Department_Code in '306','307','308','309','310','311','312','313','314','315','318')
) b

ON a.member_card_number = b.member_card_number
    AND a.New_Store_Code = b.New_Store_Code
    AND a.CONCEPT = b.CONCEPT
```

Comment: Ok, the issue i found out is, filtering the date from different table. (select LY_To_DT from Data_Date). if i hard code the dates then the query runs very fast. but why i am taking the dates from different table is becos i need to prepare this report every week for more than 100 locations. and to change the dates all the place is not feasible. any option??.

Comment: Please provide a SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Sorry but i m using 10G and it doesnt support monitor tools in sql developer .